# Cost of GC in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently I was asked in one the interviews :

What is the cost of Garbage collection in java ?

I answered as : By collecting ununsed objects, we can free up the heap space , in order to avoid OutOfMemoryError.

but it seemed to me like , the interviewer was not satisfied.

Kindly help me in knowing costs of GC in Java.

Comment: GC in java is abstracted to the JVM and can happen at different times dependent on what JVM is running

Comment: How does your answer describe a "cost"? A cost is resources that need to be spent in order to achieve your task, such as memory and processing time. "What is the cost of garbage collection" means "How much memory and processing time are spent on garbage collection?"

Comment: Plain and simple: the cost of GC (as with so many other worthwhile things in computing and in life) is that it takes some time to do it.  Time spent doing GC is time not spent doing the "real" work of the program.

Comment: RealSkeptic : agree to your point to some extent.Could you please help me in knowing what really is the cost of GC

Comment: What costs are we talking about, CPU cycles, RAM, dollars, reputation, development, maintenance, hardware acquisition, human resources? What’s the baseline, a hypothetical Java without garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection involves complex memory management and may requires important CPU resources ... There are various GC strategies based on the type of application and the JVM you are running.

If your application creates and releases large amounts of memory, garbage collection may take "some" non negligible amount of CPU and may even lock your application for some time.

Depending on the purpose of your application, this may be acceptable or not. You have to chose a GC strategy based on your needs. This article explains the 5 strategies of OpenJDK (https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-the-right-gc).

Choosing the correct GC strategy is a compromise between periodical JVM blocking and overall efficiency and performance.

Comment: Instead of saying it requires more CPU time i would say it would require more logic because GC could be implemented in Hardware rather than Software.

Comment: @Lee that special hardware resource still would be equivalent to consuming CPU time.

Comment: @Holger that nearly that what i said, but I said also that it is better to say more logic instead of CPU time

Comment: @Lee that’s not the same. A very simple algorithm (less logic) may still consume more CPU resources than a complex algorithm. But anyway, this widespread “gc requires more logic/resources” assertion might not be true. A program written in a language with manual memory management requires `free` or `delete` calls or similar all over the places, which already forms some logic, but further, often ignored, the underlying implementation has to keep track of all these explicitly released memory fragments and make them available to new allocations which is not necessarily simpler than the gc’s work.

Comment: @Holger Some programs where written to never allocate and free Memory, those will have no penalty except that some algorithms can only be used in limits. I used logic in form of logic units and not in terms of complexity. On the other hand you might right because even the ASIC will need some time so it will be time and logic space that will be occupied. Wherever logic is measured in LUTs, Bytes of Machine Code, transistors or whatever.

Comment: @holger the underline application to handle new and delete is trivial comparer to gc logic.

Comment: @Lee the same programs would work with Java without additional costs, as the garbage collector only performs work when there is not enough memory for subsequent allocations (or the allocations reach a configurable threshold). Without allocations, it will never kick in. There’s even a pseudo collector in recent JVMs which you can select, to force never collecting.

Comment: @cquezel obviously, you never implemented such a support code. Just think about how you maintain the fragments of thousands of explicit delete operations, merge them to counteract fragmentation and provide them for new allocations in a thread safe way, without paying the cost of thread synchronization for every allocation and deletion.

Comment: @Holger yes that is trough i even wrote myself some Java Applets basically consist of only one big class and only minimum of Instances from Standard library. Its gave me an huge speed up and increased stability when execute by MSJVM in IE.

Comment: @Holger I wrote "trivial compared to gc logic". You don't have to implement such support to know that it is much easier than GC. Just lookup the various articles on CG complexity and notice that when all these solutions are implemented, in the end, they still have to use a memory manager à la C/C++.

Comment: @cquezel there are two types of articles, those which just hold the old “gc is slow” myth and the others, which discuss sophisticated implementations which try to achieve the maximum performance, regardless of how they compare to manual memory management. Obviously, you never read a similar article about the C/C++ internals. And no, these operations are not going through the memory manager of the underlying system, as the heap stays pre-allocated most of the time. There’s a difference between making tens thousands (de)allocations per second or adapting the overall heap size every ten seconds.

Comment: @Holger My writing style must be confusing or maybe its your reading skills but I did not write anything about "the memory manager of the underlying system".

Comment: @cquezel you wrote “they still have to use a memory manager à la C/C++”, apparently under the assumption that a JVM has to be implemented atop a language like C/C++. So the “memory manager à la C/C++” is the manager of the JVM’s underlying system when being implemented that way. My statement generalized that, as regardless how the JVM is implemented, you are correct in that the JVM has to use an underlying memory manager. But it uses it only rarely, sometimes only once at the beginning. Which is the reason, why the complexity is entirely independent of it.

Comment: @Holger "apparently under the assumption that a JVM has to be implemented atop a language like C/C++". "à la" means similar to. i.e. explicitly not necessarily C/C++.

Comment: And “like” C/C++ also means “à la” or “not necessarily” C/C++. That’s why I used the even more abstract term “underlying system”. I don’t understand why you have so much difficulties with these phrases.